# How to obtain the numerical value of a dimension object with respect to an arbitrary dimension, in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, expl3, dimensions

Does TikZ provide a way of obtaining the numerical value of a dimension object with respect to an arbitrary dimension? If so, great. If not, would you please help me debug the following attempt to write a command `\stripdim` that accomplishes the goal stated above?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\stripdim}{mm}{ \dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn{#1}{1#2} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\edef\num{\stripdim{3cm}{cm}}
\draw node{\num};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The code above prints `3`, as desired. However, if the `\draw` command is replaced by the following:

```
\draw let \n1=\num in node{\n1};
```

the compilation fails, and the following message is found in the log:

```
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
)
l.13 \draw let \n1=\num
                      in node{\n1};
? 
! Emergency stop.
<to be read again> 
)
l.13 \draw let \n1=\num
                      in node{\n1};
End of file on the terminal!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your edef is not expanding anything, if you add `\show\num` you see:

```
> \num=macro:
->\stripdim {3cm}{cm}.
l.14 \show\num
              
?
```

Use an expandable command:

```
> \num=macro:
->3.
l.14 \show\num
              
?
```

---

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\stripdim}{mm}{\dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn{#1}{1#2} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\edef\num{\stripdim{3cm}{cm}}
\show\num
\draw node{\num};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```